# Use LINQ to retrieve multiple scalar values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am wondering if there is some clever way to retrieve data from an enumerable using LINQ when individual values from multiple records are needed.

For example, let's say you have a person with three different phone fields:

```
public class Person
{
    public Phone HomePhone { get; set; }
    public Phone WorkPhone { get; set; }
    public Phone CellPhone { get; set; }
}
```

...but the phone list is stored in a normalized format:

```
public enum PhoneType 
{
    Home, Work, Cell
}

public class Phone
{
    public PhoneType Type   { get; set; }
    public string    Number { get; set; }
}

static public IEnumerable<Phone> GetPhoneList()
{
    yield return new Phone { Type = PhoneType.Home, Number = "8005551212" };
    yield return new Phone { Type = PhoneType.Work, Number = "8005551313" };
    yield return new Phone { Type = PhoneType.Cell, Number = "8005551414" };
}
```

If you needed to populate Person, you could write a loop, and get everything you need in one pass:

```
public static Person GetPerson1()
{
    var result = new Person();
    foreach (var ph in GetPhoneList())
    {
        switch (ph.Type)
        {
            case PhoneType.Home: result.HomePhone = ph; break;
            case PhoneType.Work: result.WorkPhone = ph; break;
            case PhoneType.Cell: result.CellPhone = ph; break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But if you wanted to use LINQ, it seems like three passes may be needed:

```
public static Person GetPerson2()
{
    return new Person
    {
        HomePhone = GetPhoneList().Single( ph => ph.Type == PhoneType.Home ),
        WorkPhone = GetPhoneList().Single( ph => ph.Type == PhoneType.Work ),
        CellPhone = GetPhoneList().Single( ph => ph.Type == PhoneType.Cell )
    };
}
```

Is there a clever way to use LINQ to get it all with only one pass over the enumeration?

Here is a [link to a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Tg3IZp) if you'd like to explore my code.

(I am aware I could use a dictionary or other data structure to solve this particular problem; this is just an example.)

Comment: You could maybe put the phone numbers in a dictionary: `var phoneNumbers = GetPhoneList().ToDictionary(ph => ph.Type, ph);` and then simply lookup the phone number in the dictionary with `HomePhone = phoneNumbers[PhoneType.Home]`, or is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Ha... you posted this comment less than a minute after I edited my post to say, "yes, I know, dictionary, but." This is just an example. Imagine if the selection criteria were too complicated to be abstractified as a dictionary key, e.g. if multiple columns needed to be examined.

Comment: @nbokmans suggestion makes sense, use dictionary or lookup type and then lookup those

Comment: Even if the selection criteria is more complex you can still do it with a dictionary. Just put the switch in the key selector and return something that you later can do a lookup on.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, you can't do this in LINQ.

If you really want to, you can create a Foreach extension method and do the same as your `GetPerson1` method.

```
public static class Ext
{
    public static void Foreach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> e, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T item in e)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
    public static Person GetPerson2()
    {
        var p = new Person();
        var pl = GetPhoneList();
        pl.Foreach(ph =>
        {
            switch (ph.Type)
            {
                case PhoneType.Home: p.HomePhone = ph; break;
                case PhoneType.Work: p.WorkPhone = ph; break;
                case PhoneType.Cell: p.CellPhone = ph; break;
            }                
        });
        return p;
    }
```

But you really shouldn't. LINQ is meant to operate on IEnumerables (item by item), and LINQ functions should be without side effects, while your foreach loop and Foreach extension methods are only creating side effects, changing the state of the Person object.

And, besides, the fact that you need a 'clever way' should be an indication that this is not the way it's meant to be used :)

There's a great article by Eric Lippert with more details here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/

Answer (score 3):

If there is no guarantee that numbers from the same person come in a sequence then you have to enumerate the list until you find all the numbers. It does not seem to me this is a good candidate for LINQ, whose purpose is to make the code more readable. Your `foreach` is just fine, and I would just break the loop when all numbers are found.

If you want to enumerate all the persons, and not just one then `Dictionary` approach is probably most effective. `GroupBy` internally uses a dictionary and you can use `GroupBy` to collect all the numbers belonging to a person, and then `Aggregate` to make a `Person` out of them. Let's assume there is some property `Phone.PersonID`, and also `Person.PersonID`, then you would have something like this:

```
GetPhoneList()
    .GroupBy(x => x.PersonID)
    .Select(x => x.Aggregate(new Person() { PersonID = x.Key },
        (person, phone) =>
        {
            switch (phone.Type)
            {
                case PhoneType.Home: person.HomePhone = phone; break;
                case PhoneType.Work: person.WorkPhone = phone; break;
                case PhoneType.Cell: person.CellPhone = phone; break;
            }

            return person;
        }));
```

I assume here that `GetPhoneList()` returns all the phones of all persons.